# Help with Orbot/Tor on Kindle

Tags: orbot, help, troubleshooting

When I launch Orbit it says I'm connected to the Tor network but when I do the browser check it says I am not. Can anyone help me with this problem, much ado prepared.

Comment: What browser did you tried? Was that browser setted up correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have the best results using a separate dedicated tor proxy like the tor hardware router, or configuring your network settings on the kindle to use  tor on a dedicated machine somewhere else on your network via proxy.

The failure at the check.torproject.org site could be either dns or proxy settings, and even when it is configured correctly there is a chance your ip and other info could be leaked. If you really want to try orbot, it sounds like it would be worth it to try re-installing from scratch.